# AWS ElasticBeans With Eureka and Zuul , how to Restrict access to services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, netflix-zuul

I have created a full micro services solution on AWS elasticBeansTalk(each service in its own container) on port 5000(default port for elasticbeans) -> this creates each micro service in its own security group.

I am using Zuul and eureka and everything is working great,
But my problem is that I had to create inbound and outbound rules for all of my containers(with all IP white listed 0.0.0.0/0).

I would like to block public access to each of the micro services except Zuul and the spring config server(And I am a really bad devops guy), 
can Anyone help me with the correct configuration? 
Many thanks and Kind regards,
Roie Beck

I am attaching an image of the structure(there is also a config server in there but I didn't find an image of one):

[image: Configuration]

Comment: Hi Roie. any update on this query? I am facing the same situation and would like to know the solution u have implemented.!

Comment: Hi @Ashwin, please look at the comment below, it is exactly what you want,
all the services except gateway should sit in a vpc and talk via NAT gateway(private sub network),
the zuul (or SCG) should use aws internet gateway and should be the only public container(public sub network).
 please look at the link below by danzdoran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to create a private subnet to run all of your micro-services and have your zuul gateway proxy all requests in your public subnet. Zuul and the micro-services can communicate through the NAT-gateway.  More information can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html